# Cross Domain Ajax Request with JQuery/PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Help, if you can-

The situation:

http://foobar.com includes a remotely hosted javacript file (http://boobar.com/stuff.js).

The goal is to just get an alert from the remotely hosted php script on foobar.com

I have tried the following code in stuff.js:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://www.boobar.com/script.php?callback=?",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(result) { alert(result); }
});
```

No luck.

```
$.getJSON("http://www.boobar.com/script.php?jsonp=?",
  function(data) { alert(data); }
);
```

Also no luck.

On the php side I have tried both the following:

```
return json_encode(array(0 => 'test'));

echo json_encode(array(0 => 'test'));
```

In Firefox I get a security error. I understand that it thinks I'm violating the security model. However, according to the jquery documentation, I should be able to accomplish this.

Comment: So what I ended up doing, since it was just a GET - no data need to be retrieved - I used JQuery to create a hidden iframe with the URL including the variables I wanted to pass set as the source. Worked like a charm. To all who provded feedback - Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error seems to be a security feature of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy): to simplify, you can only make AJAX requests for stuff on the originating server (`http://foobar.com`). One way around this is to make a simple facade on the originating server, e.g.:

```
 <?php
 // this file resides at http://foobar.com/getstuff.php
 echo file_get_contents('http://www.boobar.com/script.php?callback=?'
          . $possibly_some_other_GET_parameters );
 ?>
```

Then, from foobar.com, you can make an AJAX request for `http://foobar.com/getstuff.php` (which in turn makes a HTTP GET request *from your web server* to `boobar.com` and sends it back to the browser).

To the browser, the request goes to the origin server, and is allowed (the browser has no way of knowing that the response comes from somewhere else behind the scene).

Caveats:

- the PHP config at foobar.com must have `allow_url_fopen` set to "1". Although this is the default setting, some servers have it disabled.
- the request to www.boobar.com is made from foobar.com **server**, not from the browser. That means no cookies or user authentication data are sent to www.boobar.com, just whatever you put into the request URL ("`$possibly_some_other_GET_parameters`").

Comment: For the last step, the cookies and authentication, maybe it can be done with cURL i guess

Comment: I'd use cURL too, but I have used `file_get_contents` as a simple example.

Answer (score 4):

You can get data from another server asynchronously using script tags and json:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://somesite.com/path/to/page/"></script>
```

You can use this to dynamically load a remote javascript (by created a new script element and setting the src attribute, then loading into the DOM), which could set a variable. However, you need to really **trust** the remote site, because the JS will be evaluated *without any precondition*.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method called `window.name transport` or `window.name method` which uses a general browser bug(not sure if this is a bug actually). You make the request through an iFrame and the loaded page puts the information you need to the "name" property of the JavaScript window object of itself.

This method uses a "blank.htm" since it first navigates to the target page and then goes back to the blank.htm page to overcome the "same origin policy" restriction.

Dojo have implemented this and you can find a more detailed explanation [here](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/22/windowname-transport/).

Also I have implemented a cross-domain XMLHttpRequest object based on this method in the library I have written which can be found [here](http://jslib-test.amplio-vita.net/JSLib/js/aV.main.ajax.js).

You may not be able to use the library since it will need 1 or 2 additional libraries which can be found [here](http://jslib-test.amplio-vita.net/JSLib/js).

If you need further help in implementing it in your style, I'll try to do my best.

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up doing, since it was just a GET - no data need to be retrieved - I used JQuery to create a hidden iframe with the URL including the variables I wanted to pass set as the source. Worked like a charm. To all who provded feedback - Thanks!

Comment: How?  Please provide details.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about this !! Using a php proxy.

Cross-Domain AJAX calls using PHP
http://www.phpfour.com/blog/2008/03/cross-domain-ajax-using-php/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery .ajax also has a setting 'crossDomain'.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
crossDomain (default: false for same-domain requests, true for cross-domain requests)
Type: Boolean
If you wish to force a crossDomain request (such as JSONP) on the same domain, set the value of crossDomain to true. This allows, for example, server-side redirection to another domain. (version added: 1.5)
```