# PHP JQuery cross domain

Tags: php, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross Domain Ajax Request with JQuery/PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752319/cross-domain-ajax-request-with-jquery-php)

I hope you can help
I have a php page on a subdomain which onclick needs to execute a PHP script on the main domain with a GET request. For some reason

```
$.get("http://www.domain.com/page", {param: param}, function(data){alert(data);});
```

Is returning a 404 error. The page is definiately there and will run when the url is entered directed.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 2):

Look up the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and [JSONP](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#XMLHttpRequest)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are trying to load a file directly off of another origin. Browsers prevent this (making you get a 404 error).

You can read about the exact details here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

add this to your php files:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
```