# jquery.get() - can't get the results

Tags: jquery, http, url, get

I just can't get the results from jquery.get() function and can't figure out why.

Here's the code:

```
$('#some_button').live('click', function (e){
  var nr="some_number";
  var id="some_id";
  $.get('http://www.somelink.com',{PAGE_ID: id, nr: nr}, function(data) {
    alert(data);
  });
});
```

So, when I click the button, HTTP request is sent and after 10 seconds I get the reply   and the result that I need with HTTP 200 OK (I used wireshark), but the data is not alerted back to the browser.

Any ideas why?

BR,
Newman

Comment: Is this a crossdomain request?

Comment: Are you trying to obtain data from that "<http://www.somelink.com>" or are you trying to obtain just information from the page from that link?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/752319/901048

Comment: Information. When I post data with GET, in return I get some info that I need. Guess I'll need some other solution since this is a cross domain issue.

Comment: What confused me is that request is sent and information that I need is returned but can't be displayed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be using `$.get` to obtain information from a different domain, which is prohibited by all respectable browsers. You can only use `$.get` on same-domain requests.

Comment: Oh, I totally forgot about this! Or should I say, I thought that this works with jquery get() :)   So any idea how to bypass this?

Comment: The only way to get data cross-domain is with JSONP -- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp -- and this uses a very specialized format.

Comment: You can also use a server-side script to scrape the other domain and serve that up with `$.get` instead: http://phpfour.com/blog/2008/03/cross-domain-ajax-using-php/

Comment: I think I'll use the server side script..THank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

The reason could quite not what your expecting, Assuming your trying to request something from a different domain then where the script is running. Your browser will be causing a `Cross Domain` error.

You could use `jsonp` or interperatate the request on your own server.

[This (Cross Domain AJAX Querying with jQuery)](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html) May help