# Read RSS from a Wordpress website

Tags: ajax, wordpress, rss, cordova

I am developing a Phonegap application. I read RSS feeds from the website and display it in an appropriate way. The problem is that I get Access-Control-Allow-Origin problem .
This is the code That I am using . forget about the success function I was just trying .

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://fixit.ps/n/pngo/?feed=rss2&cat=4",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var $xml = $(data),
        items = [];
    $xml.find("entry").each(function(i) {
        if (i === 30) return false;
        var $this = $(this);
        console.log($this);
        console.log($this.find("title").text());
        console.log($this.find("content").text());

    });
    }
    });
```

Comment: Look at this question. hope to be useful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752319/cross-domain-ajax-request-with-jquery-php

Comment: I created a ticket in WP where asked to add this functionality https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/50441#ticket
Also in details of the ticket you may find a security concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit your header.php or index.php file and add the following code at the top before echoing any response

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
?>
```

or you can easily enable and disable Cross-Domain error using the plugin below:

https://github.com/jacopotarantino/WordPress-Cross-Domain-Plugin